# Conflicto git siempre que haces merge

Tags: git

Estoy trabajando con varias ramas en git y me gustaría que cada vez que hago un merge a master me marque como conflicto todos las diferencias y ho haga el merge automáticamente, ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

También me valdría una forma de traerme los archivos de otra rama pero que el HEAD siguiese apuntando a esta rama, para que se me marguen las diferencias como cambios.

Comment: Me resulta difícil entender qué necesitas. Pero quizás te sirva hacer `git merge <nombre-de-la-rama> --no-commit --no-ff`. Así aplicará los cambios a `master` sin crear automáticamente un commit. [Documentación de `--no-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---no-commit).

Comment: ¿Para qué ibas a querer ver los cambios como conflictos? Solo debería ser marcado como conflicto si existe un conflicto real. Si lo que quieres es ver los cambios que ha habido en el merge hay otras formas de hacerlo, entre otros, como dice  @JorgeLuis usar la opción `--no-commit` y hacer el commit tú por tu cuenta.

Comment: De todas formas y sin ánimo de ofenderte, considero que tu problema reside en la inexperiencia y desconocimiento del funcionamiento de GIT, te recomiendo hacer algún curso o verte algunos videos de internet, hay mil que explican todo esto, superbién y te enseñan mil cosas que apenas gente conoce. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas saber qué va a entrar en una rama al hacer un `merge`, la forma de hacerlo *sin hacer merge* es con un diff: `git diff rama-upstream...la-rama` o `git diff HEAD...la-rama` (si lo vas a mezclar contra tu rama actual)... importante: no son 2 puntos sino 3: `...`.